# Three.js Detect if Traverse is complete

Tags: javascript, three.js

Is there a way to check if the traverse function is complete (finished traversing the scene)?

Something like (example)

```
fbx.traverse( function( c )
    if ( c instanceof THREE.Camera ) {      
        // Debug log camera child
        console.log( c 

}).onComplete(function( e ) {
    // Do something on complete
}
```

**Explanation of problem:** Whena user selects a FBX file, it traverses it for all cameras. If it's a valid FBX file, and successfully read, it then processes `'FBX loaded. Found ' + count + ' camera(s).'`

The issue is, when I load a FBX file, I can cleary see it states "0" cameras, before the `traverse` has found a camera. Then it changes to 1. I'd like to know when the traverse is complete, so the user can be notified it's safe to export converted camera file.

Otherwise they may download before the traverse function is even complete.

**Current Code**

```
reader.addEventListener( "load", function( e )
    const buffer = event.target.result,
          loader = new THREE.FBXLoader(),
          fbx = loader.parse( buffer );
          
    var count = 0;
    
    fbx.traverse( function( c )
        if ( c instanceof THREE.Camera ) {      
            // Debug log camera child
            console.log( c 
            count+
    
    });
    
    msg.innerHTML = '<span class="green">FBX loaded. Found <strong>' + count + '</strong> camera(s).</span>';
    
    
});
```

Comment: Traversal (unlike loading the file from a URL) is synchronous — on the next line after your traverse, you can be sure the traversal is already complete. No need for an `onComplete` callback.

Comment: Hmm. That's where I have my message, but it still reads 0, before turning to 1.

Comment: I'll add the actual code to the question. Edit: Added.

Comment: Just to test – try adding a setTimeout after `loader.parse( buffer )` before continuing to count objects? I'm wondering if the `parse` method is returning an empty scene and then asynchronously adding content to it later...

Comment: @DonMcCurdy I just glanced at the `FBXLoader` code, and while there ARE parts that are asynchronous, there are no callbacks or Promises involved, and the part that reads the camera appears to be synchronous. This might need asked on the Discourse site for a deeper analysis.

Comment: I may do that. I did have success solving the issue. This code wasn't with a ready function. Once I encapsulated the script with a `document.ready` function it pops up with the desired count immediately.

Comment: Glad to hear! I'm a bit stumped by the original issue, since neither `parse` nor `traverse` should be asynchronous. If that comes up again, agreed with @TheJim01's suggestion of checking on the three.js forums or chatrooms.

Comment: Thanks, I registered on the forums for another problem I had earlier this week. Have yet to have a reply on it. c